# simply moving and creating new worksheet from one ms excel file to another. Facing name conflict popup

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Simply moving and creating new worksheet from one ms excel file to another. 
While doing so i got a popup box with the option Yes & No ... please help how to rid of this problem. 
Error
"**A formula or sheet you want to move or copy contains the name '...'(this keep on changing while choosing option YES) , which already exists on the destination worksheet. Do you want to use this version of the name?** "

*.To use the name as defined in the destination, click YES*
*.To rename the range referred to in the formula or worksheet, chick No, and enter a new name in the Name conflict dialog box*

**How many time i will click Yes or entry new Name. please help how to get rid of this popup box**

Comment: any solution ....

Answer (score 0):

So you are having conflicts of worksheet name, maybe with the default one of new file?

See if renaming your old worksheet and move to the new file can help

Btw

> Try this, Press F3, you will see list of name ranges. To delete those, press Ctrl + F3, it will pull out name ranges. You'll have the option to modify them from there

Reference [Reddit name already exists error when coping](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/3l01gd/name_already_exists_error_when_copying_any/)

Comment: hi Edward, any key only work when this popup will close. My problem is how to close this popup box